# How can I install a specific program on Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04

I have a folder containing files `main.cc` `main.o` `Makefile` `prog` `prog.pro` and `prog.pro.user` I have problem installing it. This is a program that someone wrote, and it is not available in public as a `.deb` file. I used the following commands:

1. `make` resulted in: `make: Nothing to be done for 'first'.`
2. `install` resulted in: `install: missing file operand.`
3. `prog` resulted in: `prog: command not found`
4. `./prog` resulted in: `QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified The device must be readable. Error loading the info.xml file`
5. `sudo make && make install` resulted in:`make: *** No rule to make target '../../../../anaconda/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf, needed by 'Makefile'.  Stop.`
6. `./configure` resulted in: `bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`

I also right clicked on prog, and clicked on Run. but nothing is happening.

Could you please guide me on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you tell us what the application is you're trying to install?  Usually it's the same or similar enough, but it may be different - so there's not necessarily a 'one size fits all' answer.  Provide more detail, and we should be able to help you.  ;)

Comment: Can you also clarify what you mean by "_they didn't work_" ? What exactly didn't work ? What was the output of these commands ?

Comment: prog.pro : Just run `qmake` .... or `qmake -o Makefile prog.pro` ....   I.e. qmake will generate a new  Makefile from prog.pro

Comment: I did "qmake -o Makefile prog.pro" a new Makefile from prog.pro created. now how can i run the program?

Comment: I don't understand why this question is being downvoted, as the question states:  his is a program that someone wrote, and it is not in public

Comment: @eyoung100 The first iteration (http://askubuntu.com/revisions/790279/1) of the question is unclear, so that may explain the downvotes.

Comment: I'm in the process of writing the answer now, but my thoroughness takes awhile when typing one-handed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling Software on Ubuntu requires a few extra steps, as most packages come as precompiled binaries available in the software store or in your version's repository.  Following these steps as a guideline will ensure that you can compile software easily:

1. Let's create a place for our software to live.  This ensures that we do not affect our running system, should something go wrong.  The guide linked below uses `/usr/local/src`, but I prefer `/opt`: `sudo mkdir /opt/ProgramName`.  Replace `ProgramName` with the actual name of the compiled program.
2. Move all the Items that you're trying to compile into `/opt/ProgramName`, or better yet move and extract the Tarball into `/opt/ProgramName`: `mv -v tarballname.tar.gz /opt/ProgramName && cd /opt/ProgramName/ && tar -xzvf tarballname.tar.gz`
3. With a fresh copy of the tarball extracted, we need some tools, namely the compiler, the make, and the install program: `sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall`
4. Run `./configure --prefix=/opt/ProgramName` in the root directory, `ProgramName`.  The `--prefix` parameter is very important, as this tells make not to install this in your system's default directories.  This also tells you that the package is not managed by `apt`.
5. Now if the configure script crashes, we need to install the missing dependencies. We do this by using tools provided in `apt`.  Every configure script will generate a file ending in `.pc` or `.log` when it errors: `apt-file search nameoflogfile.pc` will gather the missing dependencies.
6. Install the missing dependencies with `apt-get install missing-package-names` where `missing-package-names` is the output from Step 5.
7. Repeat Step 4.
8. Now issue `make && make install`

---

You were missing Step 4.

Please also realize that from your question that Prog.pro is a QT Project file, which requires `qmake`.  Qmake requires the QT Libraries, and by default the QT Libraries aren't installed.  Adding them will result in extra menu items etc, because Unity is supported by the GTK Libraries.  QT is most notably used for the [K Desktop Environment, aka KDE](https://www.kde.org/), which means that the person who wrote this application intended it to be used in KDE, and **NOT GNOME or Unity**.

### Update

You may need to run `autogen` script.  If you don't see that, you need to redownload/reaquire the program.  Programs are built using the [Autotools Toolchain - Tutorial](https://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html).  See Also: [WikiPedia Entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Build_System).

---

See Also: [CompilingEasyHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo)

Comment: I am trying to do your instruction.  you are right. I opened Prog.pro and it is written # Project created by QtCreator

Comment: The result of step4. is 'bash: ./configure: No such file or directory'

Comment: @golriz [QTCreator](https://www.qt.io/ide/)  is the IDE used to create mobile and possibly PC apps based on the [QT Libraries](https://www.qt.io/).  The paid version is now partly owned by Nokia, IIRC, and the OpenSource version is used in the sister application, [KDevelop](https://www.kdevelop.org/), the IDE used to create applications for KDE.  If you're running a DE based on GTK, you need to ask whoever gave this to you if they have a copy based on [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/).

Comment: For configure to work, you need to be in the proper directory.  For my example that was `/opt/ProgramName` .  If you are in that directory, you have 2 options.  Complete Step 3, or start over.  What is the output of `./configure --help`?  See my update for an example.

Comment: "golriz@golriz-pc:/opt/ProgramName$ ./configure --help" the result:
"bash: ./configure: No such file or directory"

Comment: now ProgramName folder is containing main.cc main.o Makefile prog prog.pro and prog.pro.user

Comment: isn't this problem because it is a QT project?

Comment: No the problem is that you don't have all the items needed to generate the `configure` script(namely configure.in).  Read the tutorial I provided in my update, and then [this one here](http://inti.sourceforge.net/tutorial/libinti/autotoolsproject.html) to reinforce the concept.  The fact that this is a QT Project has no bearing on the fact that you've never used Autotools.  If whoever you got this from says that it's all there, tell him or her its missing.  In fact the QTCreator Project File will Generate the autotools scripts, I think, but it's been awhile so I'm a bit rusty

Comment: @golriz You need the configure script to tell you the missing dependencies.  See Step 5.  Trying to run `make` on the `Makefile` provided to you will not work, because I can guarantee that you're missing dependencies required by the makefile.

Comment: @golriz Not a problem.  That's why StackExchange exists.